# x-editable popup not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get x-editable/bootstrap working in Rails 3 but I can only get inline editing to work - I can't get a popup

I've added the following to my gemfile (I'm already using Twitter Bootstrap)

```
gem 'bootstrap-x-editable-rails'
```

I've set up a very simple test as follows:

in the html

```
<a href="#" id="editgoal" data-type="text" data-pk="191" data-url="/post" data-original-title="edit">test</a>
```

In script

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$('#editgoal').editable();
```

On my page, when I click on the 'edit' link, I get an inline edit box

[image: inline edit box]

It looks to have Bootstrap styling ok - so everything looks right except I cant get a popup

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe the default value for the mode IS popup so you shouldn't even have to have that line in your script ($.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';). Are you sure you're not already getting the popup and just don't have all the CSS loading properly?

Comment: I got this working, but was never sure what the cure was in the end - I think it might have been a clash with JQuery stuff loaded on the same page